# How to suppress the final period (".") in paragraph titles?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs, elsarticle, journal

When I run the following code, I get the paragraph title "Some title.". How do I get the compiler to suppress the period (".") in the paragraph title?

```
\documentclass[3p,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\begin{document} 

\paragraph{Some title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to be a feature of the elsarticle class, you're using. If you're going to submit with Elsevier, let them take care of the style questions. They will overrule custom formatting anyway. Or you just pick another template.

Comment: It is in any case wrong to use `\paragraph` at that point : `\paragraph`  is the 4th level section heading so should be used below `\subsubsection`.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to make a question mark instead of a period. The question mark is easy to make so I did not ask concerning it.

Comment: @Marcus: Why wasn't this `?` addition in your post from the beginning, leaving my answer effectively useless now, being accepted and then unaccepted? :-(

Comment: @Marcus The fact that you want a question mark is a very important detail that should have been in the question to begin with.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am sorry that I did not mention the question mark. I did not want to waste space and time writing things that I did not conceive to be important. And your initial answer was not useless since it also removed the period, which was the actual challenge. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: @Marcus: Yes, it was the actual challenge. And not the question mark.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The definition in `elsarticle` is badly written, because it unconditionally adds a period.

You can change it in a way that will add the period only if no punctuation follows the title with the help of `amsthm` and its `\@addpunct` feature.

```
\documentclass[3p,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsthm}% for \@addpunct
\makeatletter
\def\els@aparagraph[#1]#2{\elsparagraph[#1]{#2\@addpunct{.}}}
\def\els@bparagraph#1{\elsparagraph*{#1\@addpunct{.}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{A title without period}

\paragraph{A title with period.}

\paragraph{Will it work with a question mark?}

\end{document}
```

There should be no problem in loading `amsthm` with `elsarticle`, because the class supports AMS packages.

Note that the period is added also to the first paragraph title, as required by the style, but no additional one follows the second title, nor one follows the question mark.

[image]

Comment: Although you stole the tick (:-( ): +1

Answer (score 14):

**Edit** Since the question mark 'issue' wasn't in the question at the time I answered I could not address this. It's useless to append this to my solution since there's another answer already.

The dot is explicitly set in `\els@aparagraph` as `#2.`

```
\def\els@aparagraph[#1]#2{\elsparagraph[#1]{#2.}}
```

A similar definition holds for `\els@bparagraph`.

Here is the working code -- but the publisher will perhaps reject this. 
In addition, what @DavidCarlisle said: The command `\paragraph` is used in the wrong hierarchy of sectioning commands.

```
\documentclass[3p,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}


\makeatletter
\def\els@aparagraph[#1]#2{\elsparagraph[#1]{#2}}
\def\els@bparagraph#1{\elsparagraph*{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\paragraph{Some title}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

And for the case that the puplisher complains that you did redefine internal commands here an add-hoc solution:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\newcommand\eatpunct[1]{}
\begin{document}
\paragraph[Bla?]{Bla?\eatpunct} Yes!
\end{document}
```

[image]